# How can we get the values entered in edittext from one activity to another?

Tags: android

I am devoloping a dictionary application and i have declared two string dynamically..

```
final String words[]={
          "Gamble", "Stress", "Stammer"
        };

final String meanings[]={
          "To play", "Tension", "To speak with involuntary pauses or repetitions "
        };
```

When the user enters the word in edittext view I want to switch to another activity if the word is found from the above array and show the meaning on the next activity.

How can I fetch the meanings array to display on second activity?

Comment: passing data form one activity to another has been discussed in many posts. Please search for Android Intent or Android send data from one activity to another!

Answer (score 1):

When you want to pass data across `Activities`, just you use `Intent` and add data to intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, Another.class);
i.putExtra("someKey", data);
startActivity(i);
```

Don't remember to add `Activity` to your `manifest.xml`.

```
<activity
   android:name=".YourActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_register"
/>
```

EDIT:

So to retrieve data in another `Activity` you use `this.getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray(<key>)` in your case when you want to pass `String[]`.

Comment: well I understand the intent part i know that...all i want to know how will i check in my second class that what was entered in my previous activity over edittext?? Like if someone entered gamble on my first screen over the edit text , how will i be able to display the meaning over my second screen ??

Comment: well thanks for the help but can u get me some help with how will i check between the two array's above that which word was entered in last activity so it can show the exact meaning of the word in the present activity?